# Rubyの開発環境を作りたい(Win7, XAMPP-PHPの環境が既にある場合 )

Tags: ruby

現在、Windows7に、XAMPP-PHP, Apache, mySQLが入っています。

このPCに、Rubyの開発環境を作りたいのですが、二つは、使い分けできるようにしたいです。
その場合のRubyの開発環境の構築方法をどのようにすれば良いのかお分かりの方、ご教授ください。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

Rubyを使いたいだけであれば、普通にインストールするだけで問題ないかと思います。
Windowsであれば、こちらからインストーラがダウンロードできます。
https://rubyinstaller.org/

インストールについて不安がある場合は、こちらのサイトを参考にすると良いでしょう。
http://www.rubylife.jp/install/install/index1.html

「使い分け」ということを気にしてらっしゃいますが、通常のインストールで問題になる点があるのでしょうか？
問題点を詳しく書くと、より具体的な回答も付くかもしれません。